# How Can I space legend items with variable spacing and have legend marker colors reflect the colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have an increasing spacing between legend items instead of a single value (`labelspacing`). The latter only accepts an `int` value type, but I want a variable spacing between legend items. Also, I want the `markerfacecolor` to follow the colormap used when creating the scatter plot.

```
N = 45
x, y = np.random.rand(2, N)

s = np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=s, s=s)

cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter,
             ax=ax,                                               
            label='Size',                                    
            fraction=0.1,                                      
            pad=0.04)

# produce a legend with a cross section of sizes from the scatter
handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop="sizes", alpha=0.6)

for hd  in handles:
    hd.set_markeredgewidth(2)
    hd.set_markeredgecolor("red")
    hd.set_markerfacecolor('blue')
    
legend2 = ax.legend(
    handles[::2], labels[::2], loc="upper right", title="Sizes", labelspacing=1.2
)
  
plt.show()
```

I searched StackOverflow and tried some possible methods but without success. Could someone guide how I can achieve the desired output?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set `markerfacecolor` as the colormap. But I am still struggling with the variable `labelspacing`!.

Any help!

```
N = 45
x, y = np.random.rand(2, N)

s = np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=s, s=s)

cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter,
             ax=ax,                                               
            label='Size',                                    
            fraction=0.1,                                      
            pad=0.04)

# produce a legend with a cross section of sizes from the scatter
handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop="sizes", alpha=0.6)

leg_colrs = [color.get_markerfacecolor() for color in scatter.legend_elements()[0]]

for hd, color  in zip(handles, leg_colrs):
    hd.set_markeredgewidth(2)
    hd.set_markeredgecolor("red")
    hd.set_markerfacecolor(color)
    
legend2 = ax.legend(
    handles[::2], labels[::2], loc="upper right", title="Sizes", labelspacing=1.2
)
  
plt.show()
```